# Laravel GraphQL UUID as ID does not work as expected

Tags: laravel, graphql, uuid

I'm using GraphQL in Laravel and I'm encountering this issue:

I've set `id` type to **string** but when I get my query through GraphQL, I get `553366` instead of `0553366c-6ebe-4340-8929-419ad46f4d15`.

Here is my type definition:

```
public function fields(): array
{
    return [
        'id' => [
            'type' => Type::string()
        ],
        'name_en' => [
            'type' => Type::string()
        ],
        'name_fa' => [
            'type' => Type::string()
        ],
        'description' => [
            'type' => Type::string()
        ],
        'img_url' => [
            'type' => Type::string()
        ],
        'created_at' => [
            'type' => Type::string()
        ],
        'updated_at' => [
            'type' => Type::string()
        ],
        'SubBusinessFields' => [
            'type' => Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('SubBusinessField'))
        ],
    ];
}
```

I've `dd()` the `id` and it was correct.

I've also tried **id** type instead of **string** but nothing changed.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added this line to my `Model` and it got fixed!

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

It was weird that I couldn't find any similar problem anywhere else.